# Maximum language.properties file size in liferay custom portlets

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, portlet

When i am trying to add a Language.properties file with thousands of keys with longtext values.
Unable to retrieve the value in my jsp file using `<liferay-ui:message key="xyz" />`. It is not displaying any value and shoing the key in its output. 
may i know the maximum number of keys or max file size it supports.
I am using liferay 6.0.6 with Tomcat bundle.

In my properties file it contains 7600 lines with large values of keys.

```
InputStream stream = application.getResourceAsStream("/abc.properties");
Properties prop=new Properties();
prop.load(stream);
```

It is giving the following error if i am using the above code to retrieve the data from another properties file.

```
 08:14:08,936 ERROR [jsp:154] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
       at java.util.Properties.loadConvert(Properties.java:569)
       at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:392)
       at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:342)
       at org.apache.jsp.html.ahadith.sb_005fview11_jsp._jspService(sb_005fview11_jsp.java:158)
       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
       at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:316)
       at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:105)
       at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:328)
       at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:343)
       at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doDispatch(MVCPortlet.java:291)
```

Thanks in Advance,
Shahbaz Khan

Comment: Can you try with less properties in file to check if your configuration is fine?

Comment: Yes I tried with less properties and it works and when i am adding more properties in thousands its not working.

Answer (score 3):

Liferay Portal itself comes with ~7400 lines in the platform's file, and they work fine. What is the order of size that you're having problems with? I'm not aware of any size-related limitation, other than it being kept in memory.

You should take care of encoding though and make sure that your file is UTF-8 encoded.

Another way to check if you're really suffering from size rather than from particular values that are causing exceptions (did you check your logfile?) is:

- You say that with a "smaller" file everything is working well. Let's name this content A
- You also say that when you add several thousand lines (let's call them B) to the file, the result of A+B doesn't work
- How about if you try just with B: If there's offending content, encoding, etc. within that file, you'll find out this way.

Also, speaking of thousands of language keys, this sounds like a quiet impressive lot, considering that the whole portal (which is of an impressive size already) gets along with ~7400 keys. It's almost worth questioning if an architectural change is in order - but then this is just a gut feeling and you'll know your application better than me, and you can judge what kind of translation you need in it.

**Edit**: Now that you've edited your question, including an actual stacktrace: Yes, you have an encoding problem. Use the jdk's `native2ascii` program to convert your ISO-8859-1 encoded properties file to UTF-8. Then use the file through Liferay: It looks like you're reading this file from the jsp - this means that most likely you'll do so on every page request, an easy way to kill your portal's performance.

Note that Liferay reads properties files as UTF-8, while `Properties.load(Stream)` always assumes ISO-8859-1, so you have to decide between using `<liferay-ui:message key="some-key"/>` and loading the resource bundle yourself. Both won't work.

Comment: As you clearly have a unicode escape there, you might need `native2ascii -reverse -encoding utf8 Language.properties > utf8-Language.properties`. Then use the new file. Or, if you literally have \uxxxx in the file, you might need to quote the \ character, as otherwise 'xxxx' would be expected to be hex (because \u starts a unicode sequence), try \\uxxxx. Also, you'll *have to decide* if you're using a portlet resource bundle (needs to be UTF-8) *or* if you're loading with Properties.load() (needs to be ISO-8859-1). Both don't work at the same time, as I've outlined above.

Comment: I again removed some of the content of Language.properties file and now it contains 3600 lines of properties its working fine whereas if i am increasing this to 3700 its not working or reading from thhe property file. The file size of language.properties file is 10.0MB with 3600 lines of code.

Comment: Try *just* the 100 lines that make the difference between 3600 and 3700. According to what you posted, you **don't** have a problem with the number of entries, but with one (or some) particular entry that suffers wrong **encoding**.